# Specifying attributes to be aggregated by STHSink

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I am investigating NGSISTHSink.
When STHSink is configured, the default setting is that all Notifications sent to Cygnus are aggregated.

Is there a setting to aggregate only some attributes of the Notification?

For example, from the room entity's attributes such as room name, temperature and humidity, etc., only the temperature and humidity are aggregated.(The room name is not written to the DB.)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must design your NGSI subscriptions so only the chosen attrs are sent to a given SOURCE-SINK.

In this way you may have different SINKS with different configurations (in this case maybe different agg periods), which attrs you send to which SOURCE-SINK get "configured" via different subscription/notification configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would like to send all attributes to MongoSink and write the history, and send only some attributes to STHSink and aggregate them, is this difficult? (e.g. using two Cygnus?). Thank you in advance.

Comment: No. Just need two subscriptions one for RAW data and another for Aggregated data. You don't need two Cygnus!! Just one Cygnus may listen on different ports (PORT-SOURCE-CHANEL-SINK) and redirect notifications to the corresponding SINK (you may also use other mechanism like FLUME "header multiplexing" along with NGSI custom notification to add a custom header). Take a look to Apache FLUME documentation, the technology behind Cygnus.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
It seems that if I separate the ports as you say, I can use MongoSINK and STHSink differently.
Thanks for the very helpful information!

Comment: That's the point. Different data flows for different capabilities, so you may choose which SINKS to apply just by configure your subscriptions. For example you could have one channel for RAW, other for AGGR and another for BOTH.